# Java Regex - need help on number match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match all the values `1` to `18` from string `24-15-7-49-63-2` using regex. I used regex before for general purpose but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: I hope this will help you, if you are using .Net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I don't know why this was tagged `c#` and `java`, but since the accepted answer is in Java, I've removed the other tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky thing is that you cannot easily define ranges with regexes. But this might do what you want:

```
\b([1-9]|1[0-8])\b
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v8jj

Here's an example in java:

```
String text = "24-15-7-49-63-2";
String pattern = "\\b([1-9]|1[0-8])\\b";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Outputs:

```
15
7
2
```

**Edit:**
Based on the comment you can get unique matches using this pattern:

```
\b([1-9]|1[0-8])\b(?!.*\b\1\b.*)
```

In action: http://regexr.com?2v8kh

Comment: Great thanks man. Please help me out a little more. How can I write this so that it wont capture which appeared before? I mean wont capture repeated value.

Comment: You'll probably don't want to do that with regex but in your code. One solution would be to add each match to a set which holds only unique numbers.

Comment: If you're using Java have a look at: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html. The first line says: "A collection that contains no duplicate elements."

Comment: Actually I was asking - how to do it with regex.

Comment: @Barun have a look at my edit. And you should update your question to contain this requirement aswell.

Comment: Little problem. Not getting 2 when string is like this 24-15-7-49-63-2-23